# Brightness Control not working on Lenovo Thinkpad(Intel Graphics)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, brightness

I am using Lenovo Thinkpad 14-inch laptop with ubuntu 16.04. The brightness is neither changing using the brightness control buttons nor using the system settings. I have tried various solutions present in the internet but nothing worked!

This is something I found would be helpful to fix it:

Output of `sudo lshw -numeric -C display`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation [8086:9B41]
   vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't update to a more recent version of Ubuntu? What kernel version are you using?

Comment: @Nandete82 yes ubuntu 16.04 is my project requirement. My kernal version is 4.15.0-107-generic.

Comment: First you run ```sudo apt-get update```. This update all your repositories for all your apps to all the latest updates lists. Then run ```sudo apt-get dist-upgrade``` to download and install those packages. It will also remove obsolete packages.

Comment: If you are using the latest version of the kernel supported on 16.04, you will need to wait for someone with more knowledge on this issue.
Check also [link] (launchpad.net), as there are known bugs with lenovo and the brightness control.